# Importing Text Files To Python And Spintax Then Outputting Text

Tags: python, import, spintax

I'm stuck on how to accomplish this. What I have is a folder of say 10 text files and in each text file is a article done in spintax, example: {This is|Here is} {My|Your|Their} {Articles|Post}

Each text file contains a full article with paragraphs in spintax. What I'm wanting to do is randomly grab from that folder one article, spin it off the spintax and then output/save it as a new text file or append to file.

I've tried to find some examples of how to do this but have had no success.

Comment: What examples have you tried?

Comment: More importantly, please show your effort before asking for help. We are not spending our time to do your homework from beginning to end. The time from everyone of us is as valuable as yours.